# Resources for learning computations using Adam Spectral Sequences.

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, online-resources, spectral-sequences, reference-works

I am trying to learn computations of homotopy groups of spheres using Adam and Adam Novikov Spectral sequences. Are there any resources that help me in learning this as quick as possible?

I want to see concrete examples of calculations, please.

Comment: Ravenel's green book ("Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres") is one option. What have you looked at so far?

Comment: I think it is not a book to start with @JohnPalmieri I tried to read chapter 4 without reading the preceding chapters, but it was hard. I want concrete examples of computations. Which part of it do you recommend for novices?  One of my colleagues graduated from University of Cambridge and he\she agreed with me that it is not a book to start with.

Comment: Again, what have you looked at so far? Presumably you're not starting from the beginning of algebraic topology, so what do you already know? I agree that starting chapter 4 of Ravenel's book would be tough going. How about chapters 1, 2, and 3? Regardless, it's hard to answer your question without knowing more about your background.

Comment: I am a novice in computations. I am trying to read chapter 9 of the user guide to spectral sequence. the thing is that I want to learn so fast so that I can run programs that give me the differentials like the one of Chatham Hood @JohnPalmieri

Comment: I will try to start with chapter 1,2 and 3. The thing is that I am seeing people just do not read all of the books in details to understand because actually when I ask about the details in the books they do not know but they try to understand what is required only@JohnPalmieri